# Dropdown menu save the choice on reload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to create popup language dropdown menu with country name, flag and link to the language version of the site. After user select menu item - it should take you to the needed url (language version of the page) and this choice should stay visible on the new page (after reload). 
Example of the menu - https://prnt.sc/sjumj8 (https://www.farfetch.com/shopping/women/items.aspx)

Here is an example of what I'm trying to create: `https://jsfiddle.net/Okean/8x0atLpy/62/`

```
<ul class="list-unstyled" id="select-lang">
    <li class="init">[SELECT]</li>
    <li data-value="value 1"> <a href="#"> <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/197/197615.svg"> Language 1 </a> </li>
    <li data-value="value 2"> <a href="#"> <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/197/197386.svg">Language 2 </a> </li>
    <li data-value="value 3"> <a href="#"> <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/197/197484.svg">Language 3 </a> </li>
    <li data-value="value 4"> <a href="#"> <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/197/197380.svg">Language 4 </a> </li>
</ul>

$("ul").on("click", ".init", function() {
    $(this).closest("ul").children('li:not(.init)').toggle();
});

var allOptions = $("ul").children('li:not(.init)');
$("ul").on("click", "li:not(.init)", function() {
    allOptions.removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $("ul").children('.init').html($(this).html());
    allOptions.toggle();
});



window.onload = function() {
    var selItem = sessionStorage.getItem("SelItem");  
    $('#select-lang').val(selItem);
    }
    $('#select-lang').change(function() { 
        var selVal = $(this).val();
        sessionStorage.setItem("SelItem", selVal);
    });

body{
  padding:30px;
}
ul { 
    height: 30px;
    width: 150px;
    border: 1px #000 solid;
}
ul li { padding: 5px 10px; z-index: 2; }
ul li:not(.init) { float: left; width: 130px; display: none; background: #ddd; }
ul li:not(.init):hover, ul li.selected:not(.init) { background: #09f; }
li.init { cursor: pointer; }

a#submit { z-index: 1; }

li img {
  width: 20px;
}
```

Comment: if you want something to persist between reloads, then you need to save the information somewhere. So you could save the selected language in the Session on the server, or in something like localstorage on the browser. have you done any research into this at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use localStorage. Once user is selected an option, you can save it to browser's local storage where 'language' is your key and you can name it anything and where 'selectedOption' is the language user has selected.

```js
// Set the preference
window.localStorage.setItem("language", selectedOption);

// Get the preference, anytime you want once set
window.localStorage.getItem("language")
```